# Parse a value = "pair" string into Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to parse a string to retrieve all **value = "pair"** of this string. I choose to do that with a simple regular expression. My regex is correct but I don't remember how simply convert my result, my MatchCollection in a simple key, value Dictionary.

```
string headerName = context.Headers["Authorization"];
/* Authorization header
OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_nonce="K7WmP9YrR2oCYC3", oauth_timestamp="1413801976", oauth_consumer_key="test", oauth_signature="8ad2fZh23q%2FWfK6RykqcvhlLxH4%3D" */
string pattern = "(?<Keyword>\\w+)\\s*=\\s*\\\"(?<Value>\\w+)\\\"";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(headerName, pattern);

Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();

foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    dictionary.Add(match["Keyword"], match["Value"]); // This is wrong
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is right:

```
dictionary.Add(match.Groups["Keyword"].Value, match.Groups["Value"].Value);
```

You need to get the match group first from the Groups collection and then get the group's value.

Answer (score 3):

Should work:

```
var dic = matches.Cast<Match>()
                 .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups["Keyword"].Value,
                               m => m.Groups["Value"].Value);
```

P.S. I wouldn't use RegEx here but simple string procesing:

```
string header = context.Headers["Authorization"];
string[] pairs = header.Split(',');
var dic = pairs.Select(p => p.Trim().Split('='))
               .ToDictionary(p => p[0], p => p[1]);
```

It's simpler.

Comment: This is correct also. I just don't like using this kind of writing when a loop do the same and do it faster. Yeah I know we are a minority of programmers to think like this. And this is not respecting my KISS rule. Yes this is KISS but the loop is more KISS (Keep It Simple and Stupid).

Comment: Why do you think loop will be faster? How faster? Using a lambda may add some overhead. But I think it will be insufficient. Comparing to better readability. Just my opinion. One loop is ok, two loops are ok. But hundreds of loop is hell.

Comment: @B413: Please see my update answer. It should satisfy your request for simplicity :)